# Example of an endomorphism on space of continuous functions with infinite norm

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Thinking about endomorphisms with infinite norms on infinite dimensional spaces, I tried to come with an example on $C(\mathbb {R} )$, and I am confused: would endomorphism $\phi: f(x) \rightarrow x^2 f(x)$ work?

Note: define norm of a function $f := \sup_{x \in \mathbb {R}} |f(x)|$

It is an endomorphism, because we're multiplying by a nice continuous function.

$||\phi|| = \sup_{|f|\le1} x^2 f(x)$, and that just goes to infinity, so $\phi$ does have an infinite norm here.

Am I right? I have doubts because it seems weirdly trivial

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not correct. The problem is that if you want the norm to be $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)|$ then you must be working in the normed vector space of *bounded* continuous functions $V = C_b(\mathbb{R})$, and $\phi$ is not an endomorphism of this vector space because it does not send bounded functions to bounded functions; e.g. $\phi(1) = x^2$ is not bounded, so it is not in $V$ at all.

If you want to exhibit an unbounded operator $\phi : V \to V$ then in particular it still needs to send bounded continuous functions to bounded continuous functions, so you have to work harder than this. Multiplication operators will not work, because in order for $\phi(f(x)) = g(x) f(x)$ to preserve bounded functions, $g(x)$ must be bounded (by taking $f(x) = 1$ as above), and then the norm of $\phi$ is just the norm of $g$.

Comment: thank you! can you give me an example that would work in this space, or any infinite dimensional space, for that matter?

Comment: @user15277629: it's a lot easier to do this with a normed vector space that isn't complete. Take $V$ to be, say, the space $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support, still equipped with the sup norm. Now your example $\phi(f(x)) = x^2 f(x)$ works fine: it sends continuous functions with compact support to continuous functions with compact support, and is unbounded (check this).